# Array with a catch

Tags: c#, arrays, input, numbers, double

Here is what I have to do:

1. Create an Array
2. User inputs 10 double elements
3. Use a catch to make sure it is valid data
4. Then display the data

Here's the code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] numbers;

    numbers = new double[10];

    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count += 1)
    {
        double num;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", numbers);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: add a `try/cath` around `Convert.ToDouble`...or better yet...`Double.TryParse`

Comment: What happens when the user enters something that isn't a number?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: To avoid the overhead that a `Try Catch` would produce; you could actually use `Regex.Match` with the `@"\d+"` which will ensure that a numeric value was entered. If you want to allow decimals, you can just format the expression to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] numbers = new double[10];

    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count += 1)
    {
        double num;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");

        while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out num))
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number");
             Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        }
        numbers[count] = num;
    }

    foreach(double item in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: "Use a **catch** to make sure it is valid data"

Comment: +1, but change the message within the `while` to something telling there was an error

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I'm using double.TryParse

Comment: Which isn't the same thing as using try/catch. The way the question is worded, I'm guessing it's homework, so the catch requirement is probably important.

Comment: @JasonWatkins Exactly what I was trying to say

Comment: Just let the teacher learn something :-P

Comment: I'm sure the teacher knows about `TryParse` (if it's a C# class). Homework assignments often include arbitrary requirements like "use a try/catch event though there are better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: You do realize, that the above example won't actually compile right?  The `numbers[i]` has an undefined value The exact error is "i does not exist in the current context.".

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Now you get a + not a minus.  Since it is correct.  Thanks for editing.

Comment: Just encase it isn't obvious, the `numbers[count] = num` should have a `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] numbers = new double[10];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        double num;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            num = double.Parse(input);
            numbers[i] = num;
            i++
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number");
        }
    }

    foreach (double d in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] numbers = new double[10];

        int counter = 0;


        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter valid number or press X to exit");
            var t = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                double temp = double.Parse(t);

                numbers[counter] = temp;
                counter++;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (t.Contains("X"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("Enter valid number or press X to exit");
            }


        } while (counter<10);

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEntered number: "+number);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```